# Can't access AJAX request parameters in a Servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I'm trying AJAX with Servlet for the first time, here is the jQuery Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/myServlet',
    contentType : 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
    success : function(result) {alert(result)},
    processData : false,
    data : authResult['code']
});
```

and here is the servlet:

```
public class Authorize extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        Date currentTime= new Date();
        String message = String.format("Currently time is %tr on %tD.",currentTime, currentTime); //printing this, echos in the ajax "success" function
        response.getWriter().print(request.getParameterMap().toString()); //this, gives me blank Map "{}" 
    }
}
```

Now, where the request parameter gone? Or how to access/send them correctly if I'm wrong?

How the response parameter are sent to AJAX in my case? And how to send them in JSON format?

Sorry if my questions seems trivial, but I searched the web a lot and couldn't find a good resource yet.

Comment: are you sure the data is sent by js? Could you try with data: { paramName: authResult['code'] } ?

Comment: You data is not setup in name-value pairs.  Try accessing the request body.

Comment: @Tylor tell me how ?!

Comment: @ianaz thanks, it worked now by sending as Json, now how to receive them in js as json ?

Comment: Set the contentType to application/json. The server should translate it into parameters automatically :)

Comment: @ianaz it acutally didn't work, I was just printing the value explicitly so I thought it works.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending a `POST` request, so your parameters are in the request body. If you want to access them as simple parameters, use `GET`:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : '/myServlet',
    contentType : 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
    success : function(result) {alert(result)},
    processData : false,
    data : authResult['code']
});
```

And in your servlet `doGet` instead of `doPost` method.

If you need post: read request body and parse then.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you have a look at [JAX-RS / Jersey](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html). It just makes things so much simpler, especially in communicating with javascript code via AJAX and JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line

> > contentType : 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',